# ASP.NET Core and JavaScript Ajax API Call to another host

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

What is the best way to handle live and dev host URL's in a JavaScript ajax API call?

For example if the dev host is https://hostdev.com/do-something and the live is https://hostlive.com/do-something how do I make this know what host to use?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'https://hostdev.com/do-something',
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    context: this,
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (result) {
        ...
});
```

Comment: You can set a global variable in the layout which defines the value of host, then in all of your ajax method, set the url as variable+"/do-something".

Answer (score 0):

if your host is `hostdev.com`
it will send to `hostdev.com/do-something`
Else send to `hostlive.com/do-something`

```
const now_host = location.hostname
const send_to_host = now_host === "hostdev.com"?"hostdev.com":"hostlive.com"

$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: send_to_host +  '/do-something',
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    context: this,
    success: function (data) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (result) {
        ...
 })
```